# How do I set 100% height of outer element for inner

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox 'table' where I'm basically trying to put an interesting thing on the top. The problem I've encountered is being unable to write it in HTML

My current result[image]

The result I'm trying to get [image]

I have tried to do it without inner `divs` and `spans`, by doing `margin:auto` but unfortunately it relocates borders from the left and right to the middle :( So the code for the current result is:

```css
.flex-container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container .middle {
  flex: 1;                       
  display: flex;                 
}

.top {
  padding-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  display:flex;
}

.leftSide {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
}

.rightSide {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  border-left-style: none;
}

.firstOption
{
 border: 2px solid #05788D;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-bottom-style:none;
}

.anotherOption 
{
 border: 2px solid #05788D;
 border-top-style: none;
 border-bottom-style:none;
 border-left-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="top">
  
 <div style="width:50%;">
    <span class="firstOption">One option</span>
 </div>
 
 <div style="width:50%;">
 <span class="anotherOption">Another option</span>
 </div>
 
  </div>

  <div class="middle">

    <div class="leftSide">
      left
    </div>

    <div class="rightSide">
      right
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `text-align` to control text-alignment of your `span` and use padding inside your `span` and don't forget to make them inline-block:

```css
.flex-container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container .middle {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.top {
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  display: flex;
}
.top div {
  flex:1;

}

.leftSide {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
}

.rightSide{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  border-left-style: none;
}
.firstOption  {
 text-align:right;
}

.firstOption span,.anotherOption span{
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="top">
    <div class="firstOption"><span>One option</span></div>
    <div class="anotherOption"><span>Another option</span></div>

  </div>

  <div class="middle">

    <div class="leftSide">
      left
    </div>

    <div class="rightSide">
      right
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: But you see, it's not 100% height of 'option' div :(

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to make a border on the left for One option and on the right for another option, so it looks exactly like on the picture?

Comment: @J.Nick sure one moment

Comment: And the last question - how can I make 'the options' in the middle of div? I mean to up it to the center

Comment: @J.Nick you mean the word `left` ?

Comment: No, one option and another option should be in the center of the impovised table cell. Also I'd like to set 20% width for each of them and make it in the center

Comment: simply use `text-align: center;` in their div container and make the span width;20%

Comment: Ohh, if I set `width:20%` it goes crazy when zoomed. And text-align:center doesn't lifts the text, it's still like glued at the bottom

Comment: @J.Nick ok got it ... so keep the code i put and simply change the padding-top ... make the top 15px and bottom 15px

Answer (score 1):

You've added `padding-top: 30px` to `class="top"`. Instead, the inner child (which are 50%) should have padding-top:30px;

While of course this can be done in a better way, above is the quickest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `justify-content: flex-end` on the left option to make it position at the end of the div. I applied the suggested changes to your code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0b5v8yj/).

I can really recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!